# AdMob disabling test ads (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, admob

I just signed up for AdMob and have got it working in my app with test advertisements (using the simulator and my iPhone). I was wondering if you need to disable test ads somehow before publishing to the App Store?

Also, should you remove the test devices code?
E.g.

```
request.testDevices = @[ @"My_iPhone", kGADSimulatorID ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to remove the test devices before you can publish. Its optional.

The kGADSimulatorID is for your emulator. keeping there there will not make any different. If you added your physical device as another test id, and want to get live ads now on that device, remove that.

Comment: I have totally removed the request.testDevices line in my code. The test banners still show up on my iPhone, and apparently also in the version I submitted to Apple: they rejected it because of test ads showing. Are there any more steps necessary to get "live" ads going?